# Custom parsing typing in dataclasses

Tags: python, mypy, python-dataclasses

As a Python user, I love keeping my code clean with `dataclasses`, and checked with `mypy`.
However, I often find myself in the case where I want to have

- a special, lax use input type, for initialization
- a stronger, parsed value thereafter

To illustrate my point, let's assume I wanted to convert the class `Foo` below into a dataclass.

```py
BarLike = Bar | str


def to_bar(x: BarLike) -> Bar:
    if isinstance(x, Bar):
        return x
    else:
        ...  # do some fancy parsing


class Foo:
    bar: Bar

    def __init__(self, bar: BarLike):
        self.bar = to_bar(bar)

    def baz(self):
        return self.bar.baz()


Bar("hello").baz()  # <- works and mypy is happy
```

This is a deliberately minimal example that is not representative of real, much more complicated usecases where the use of dataclasses is priceless to code readability.
To illustrate this point, I'll assume below that once the arguments are parsed, I want them to be immutable, with all the niceties that come with `dataclass(frozen=True)`.

I've so far thought of two ways of doing this, but both have their issues leading to necessary `# type: ignore` sprinkled around the codebase, which I would like to avoid:

### Publicly lax attribute

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
```

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    bar: BarLike

    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "bar", to_bar(self.bar))  # <- this is ugly

    def baz(self):
        return self.bar.baz()  # <- mypy complains


Foo("hello").baz()  # <- works and mypy is happy
```

### Publicly strict attribute

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    bar: Bar

    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "bar", to_bar(self.bar))  # <- this is ugly

    def baz(self):
        return self.bar.baz()


Foo("hello").baz()  # <- works but mypy complains
```

Am I missing a good way of getting the best of all worlds here?

Comment: It shouldn't be `Foo`'s business to turn maybe-a-`str` into a definitely-a-`Bar`. I also wouldn't mix that up in `to_bar` - where you do have a string, at the boundary of your program, use e.g. `Bar.from_string(...)` to turn it into a `Bar` (or fail loudly), and thereafter everything just deals with `Bar`s. There shouldn't be a point inside your codebase where `Bar | str` is needed.

Comment: This is your opinion but not what I'm trying to achieve. If Foo is customer-facing, the behaviour I'm after is much more user-friendly.

Comment: @Thrastylon could you elaborate please? What do you mean by customer-facing in your case?

Comment: Meaning that this is used by non-developers that want more of a DSL feel as an entry point. Please let's avoid the "tell me more about your life" route? I'm giving an example showing something I'm trying to achieve with the tools I can use for reasons that are my own. I'm sure C# can do this better and that embracing Zen philophy and letting go of trying to achieve this altogether are an answer, but not the one I'm coming to SO for...

Comment: Just define an `__init__` in `if TYPE_CHECKING` block (with no body) and annotate all attributes as if they are their strict versions? This way all types are exposed properly, and constructor is the one you need.